# Strange artefact visible in Layout and Rendering but not Modelling

Tags: modeling, error

I was working on a vehicle and replicated a part of the outer shell to make a rear window but when I did that, it created a strange panel that is visible in Layout, Shading and Rendering but not in Modeling.

Can anyone tell my why it's doing this? And how do I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Hi there, here's the link for it. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=X4LgPjBV" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/X4LgPjBV/)

Comment: I'll add that into your question for you in a minute. - Done!

Comment: Very odd! To be honest I've never seen anything like it. Perhaps someone else here will have an idea when the'y ve stopped seeing the new year in!

Comment: Perhaps it is geometry you hid in edit mode?  Try using `alt` + `h` while in edit mode to see if it reveals those faces.

Answer (score 0):

As *aidan-j-rhoden* said, it is hidden geometry. In *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide it.

Comment: That worked! Doing the un-hide command in edit mode did the trick. 
Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome!